# How to pass yamel file content to cloud formation nested stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I tried this in many ways:

```
 aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name agent-prod --template-file prod-agent.yaml --region eu-central-1 --parameter-overrides ConfigFile="$(cat config.yaml)"
```

and

```
 aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name agent-prod --template-file prod-agent.yaml --region eu-central-1 --parameter-overrides ConfigFile=fileb://config.yaml
```

but it didn't work. is there a good way and known to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't currently pass your parameters in YAML format. It's a [commonly requested feature](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2275).

One alternative is to pass your parameters in JSON format using the `parameters` argument:

`--parameters params.json`

params.json:

```
[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "Foo",
        "ParameterValue": "Bar"
    }
]
```